# How do I use strings in matplot?

Tags: python, matplotlib

```
months = ['August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December']
values = [0, 1000, 2000, 3000, 4000, 5000, 6000, 7000, 8000, 9000, 10000]

plt.plot(values, months)
plt.xlabel("Fall 2017 Semester Months")
plt.show()

Value error: Could not convert strings to float
```

My goal is to graph a school budget using regresive learning based on purchases being made throughout the semester. How do I use strings as variables for the x axis?

Comment: Take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2497449/plot-string-values-in-matplotlib. Hope it helps.

Comment: There is no correspondence between months and values.

Comment: Why are your lists different sizes?