# Pandas xlabel does not show values

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a pandas dataframe

```
jul.head()
```

which contains

[image]

However, when I try to plot my data, I can't figure out how to show my index values (small swarm size, medium high swarm size, ...) in my plot. 
I use

```
jul.plot(y='value', label='july').set_xlabel("config name", fontsize=12)
```

which gives me:

[image]

I can't figure out how to show the index values in the plot. Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: You need to store the indices in some array or list say `indices` and then use `plt.xticks(indices)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following should do:

```
df1=pd.DataFrame({'config name':['small', 'medium', 'large'], 'value':[-.000127, .000169, -.000206]})
plt.plot(df1.iloc[:,0], df1.iloc[:,1])
plt.xlabel('Config name')
plt.ylabel('Value')
plt.legend('Value')
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work fine in pandas 0.20. For some reason newer versions of pandas kill the ticklabels.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"value" : [0.1, 0.3, 0.2]}, index=list("ABC"))

ax = df.plot(y='value', label='july')
ax.set_xlabel("pandas "+pd.__version__, fontsize=12)

plt.show()
```

**v 0.20.1**

[image]

**v 0.23.1**

[image]

You can set the ticklabels yourself in pandas 0.23

```
ax.set_xticks(range(len(df.index)))
ax.set_xticklabels(df.index)
```

[image]

Or you can use matplotlib for plotting, as shown e.g. in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47004551/4124317).