# make ticklabels visible in pandas plot when sharex

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot, label

I want to make a grid of subplots with shared x axes. The plotting shall (for some reasons of convenience) be done by accessing the Pandas DataFrame's plot method. Also, I want to have the x-tick-labels be shown in the first row of my grid. I tried to achieve this with the following code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


x = np.linspace(0,10,100)

nrows = 4
ncols = 3
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows, ncols, sharex=True)

for i, ax in enumerate(axes.reshape(-1)):
    y = np.cos(x+i*np.pi)
    df = pd.DataFrame(y, index=x)
    # ax.plot(x, y)                 # shows top labels
    df.plot(ax=ax, legend=None)     # doesn't show top labels

    if i < ncols:
        # first row: plot x-ticks + x-labels
        ax.tick_params(which='both', labeltop=True, top=True)
        # also none of these approaches works:
        # plt.setp(ax.get_xticklabels(), visible=True)
        # ax.xaxis.set_tick_params(which='both', labeltop=True, top=True, colors='g')
        # for label in ax.get_xticklabels():
        #     label.set_visible(True)

plt.show()
```

Using the original plotting routine from Matplotlib works, but when I use the Pandas method, the ticklabels stay hidden.
Any ideas, why and how I could solve this?

Thanks a lot in advance,
Markus

Comment: you want x-ticklabels only in the first row? Or the first and the last row?

Comment: Sorry, I should've been a bit more specific; I want to have them both in the last *and* in the first row. The labels in the first row, however, should be on top of the subplots.

Comment: This is tricky. I just spend one hour on this and didn't find a solution. A similar problem already appeared [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51649816/pandas-xlabel-does-not-show-values) without any satisfying answer - not sure if it's related though.

Comment: @Markus: Ok, I made it work. See my edited answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first create the plot as you are currently doing and then later set the ticks for whichever subplot or row/column of subplot you want by creating **twin axis**.

This example sets the x-ticklabels additionally for only the first row as you want. You add these lines before `plt.show()`. `i<3` here means only the first row because that's how the subplots are accessed here in order. `both` means both major and minor ticks. Since you haven't yet shown the minor ticks, you only get major ticks at the moment. You can customize the `if` statements to add the x-ticklabels to another row if you want. I had to remove `if i < ncols:` command from your code to get it to work.

---

**Complete working code**

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib
import sys

print (sys.version)
# 3.6.5 |Anaconda, Inc.|

print (matplotlib.__version__) 
# 2.2.2

print (pd.__version__)
# 0.23.0

x = np.linspace(0,10,100)

nrows = 4
ncols = 3
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows, ncols, sharex=True,figsize=(12,6))

for i, ax in enumerate(axes.reshape(-1)):
    y = np.cos(x+i*np.pi)
    df = pd.DataFrame(y, index=x)
    df.plot(ax=ax, legend=None)     # doesn't show top labels

    if i < 3:
        ax1 = ax.twiny()
        ax1.set_xlim(ax.get_xlim())
        ax1.tick_params(axis='x', which='both', bottom=False, top=True, labelbottom=False) 

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Hi and thanks for your answer. What you suggest, works indeed for the bottom ticks/labels. But if I instead want to show the upper ticks/labels in the first row (in the last row it should still show the bottom ones), it doesn't work somehow. It displays only the ticks without the labels.
Also, what surprises me; your solution works only if I call this loop outside of the for-loop from my example. Calling the statement `if i < 3: ax.tick_params(axis='x', which='both', bottom=True, top=False, labelbottom=True)` directly in my for-loop doesn't work either.

Comment: The solution here does not work for me independent on where I put the loop. I tested with (mpl 2.2.2, pd 0.20.1) and (mpl3.0.0, pd 0.23.4).

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest: I am using `'2.2.2'` and `0.23.0`.

Comment: @Markus: Yes, you have to call this for loop after and outside your for loop.

Comment: Is there a difference when running this in jupyter vs. as script?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest, Ok I just tried it in a script and it worked there too

Comment: Thanks a lot to you two, @Bazingaa and @ImportanceOfBeingErnest, for all your effort.
@Bazingaa: Yes, now your solution also works for me. Thank you very much! Still strange though, that you need to create a `twiny` and that only setting the `tick_params` is not enough.
Also, I still don't get why one need to call an extra for-loop and couldn't implement it into the first one.
Especially, since with the builtin matplotlib routine it works without any probs.

Comment: Using a twin axes is definitely only a workaround for a bug that sits somewhere hidden.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest: Yes, fully agree. I am not sure if an issue has ever been raised formally. Perhaps you are aware of something?