# plotting pandas core series.series/values not showing

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

[image] I am trying to plot the availability of my network per hour. So,I have a massive dataframe containing multiple variables including the availability and hour. I can clearly visualise everything I want on my plot I want to plot when I do the following:

```
mond_data= mond_data.groupby('Hour')['Availability'].mean()
```

The only problem is, if I bracket the whole code and plot it (I mean this (**the code above**).plot); I do not get any value on my x-axis that says '**Hour**'.How can plot this showing the values of my x-axis (Hour). I should have 24 values as the code above bring an aaverage for the whole day for midnight to 11pm.

Comment: Why put bracket? `mond_data.groupby('Hour')['Availability'].mean().plot()` didn't work?

Comment: @bakka it gives me exactly the same thing. I did try it.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand the exact problem. What did you mean with "I do not get any value on my x-axis that says 'Hour'"?

Comment: @bakka thanks for coming back. My x-axis does not have any value whatsoever and only has only got 5 ticks

Comment: 'doesn't have any value' means no line shows in the plot?? Better if you share sample of data.

Comment: @bakka Just updated everything. The plot  is there, but I should have more ticks and also labelled ticks.

Comment: You can try something like `ax.set_xticks(mond_data.Hour.unique())`

Comment: @bakka. Thanks. I also think the problem is probably is something else . I have just wrote the same code on my MAC where I am using python 2.7 I have the values plotted automatically. That is just weird

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51649816/pandas-xlabel-does-not-show-values I think there is a bug somewhere in pandas, which noone has fixed yet.

Comment: @bakka thanks  for your assistance and  Sorry for coming back this late that's due to the time difference. I found what I was looking for . I just needed to plt.plot() then  plot index as well.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Thanks for  your assistance. Just found  what i was looking for. I will drop the answer in a bit. just a bit busy at work now. Thanks a lot

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is how I solved it.

```
plt.plot(mon_data.index,mond_data.groupby('Hour')['Availability'].mean())
```

for some reason python was not plotting the index, only if called. I have not tested many cases. So additional explanation to this problem is still welcome.

Comment: This will not create plots with `'Hour'` as the x-axis value. It will simply plot the values of `'Availability'` sequentially.

Comment: @PMende.  Thanks for your comment. Very much appreciated. As mentioned before I solved the problem. If you look at the code the index of the series has been called as well. I believe python is not seeing the index as a data column. Therefore would not plot it. On the solution I propose I am calling the index as well.